# Set value of dropdown list based on selected database record

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, dropdown

Using HTML and PHP, I am selecting and displaying records from a mysql db on a page.  When I click one record, it opens an edit window.  This new window displays all the content for one record selected and all content can be updated.  Updates are then saved to the db for this record.

My problem is this: One of the fields is displayed in the edit window as a dropdown list.  The dropdown is filled using a select on the page (similar to below).  When I click a particular record to open the edit window, I always see the first option in the drop-down, not the option that is tied to the record.
I need to be able to see the option from the dropdown that is connected to the record I am editing.

For example, if I open a record to edit it and the value as saved in the table is "3", I want "3" to appear in the dropdown.  I am always seeing the first option no matter what the actual value saved to the table is, or "1" as in the example select below.  Can someone give me some pointers please?  I would like to do this possibly using jquery.

```
<select name="itemst" id="itemst">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

The select is getting the necessary fields from the tables 
where i.item_description = d.id and i.id = '".$_GET['id']."'";

This works fine.  If I want to separately display the content of the field for a particular record/row which is connected to this drop-down, I can.  For example, echo $r_item['item_status'].  This works fine.  I just need to be able to have this value from the db display when the edit form opens and shows the dropdown.

Comment: Have you written any php for this yet?

Comment: So show us the PHP code from the select and the code you have to load the dropdown from the selection

Comment: Sorry, I am new to PHP and jquery, and I'm working with someone else's  code.  I'm trying to figure out what relevant code you would need to see.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers so far.  I have added some more information to the original question.  I am trying the suggestions, but so far no luck.  after the next hour or so, it may be a few days before I can get back at this if I don't respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work using the following.  Thanks for the suggestions.

```
               $status = $r_item['item_status'];

               <select id="item_status" name="item_status">
                   <option value="" <?php if (!empty($status) && $status == '' ) echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>></option>
                   <option value="1" <?php if (!empty($status) && $status == '1')  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>1</option>
                   <option value="2" <?php if (!empty($status) && $status == '2')  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>2</option>
                   <option value="3" <?php if (!empty($status) && $status == '3')  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>3</option>
               </select>
```

Another solution

The above works, but I have since updated it with the following:

```
               $status = $r_item['item_status'];

               <select name="item_status" id="item_status">
                   <option value="1">1</option>
                   <option value="2">2</option>
                   <option value="3">3</option>
               </select>
```

With the following line of JQuery:

`$('#item_status').val('<?=$r_item['item_status'];?>');`

And included the jquery reference in my header.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the selected attribute in HTML.

In PHP you can to do this (inside for/foreach loop):

```
<option value="1" <?=$row['yourData'] == '1' ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?> >1</option>
```

Answer (score -1):

If i understand correctly you are working on an edit form, and this field needs to show the value of the particular column of the record (row) on the database, if you are writing the **n** `<option>` for the `<select>` tag you can do it like this.

The field will be called "numeric_field" (on your database) for the example

```
$options = [1,2,3,4,5,6];  // i guess your options are hardcoded or from a table
                           // with the different options for a record
$dbRecord = function_that_returns_the_data_of_the_row_with_the_id($id);
echo "<form action="#"...>";
echo "<input.....>";    //Guess your record has other values
echo "<input.....>";    //

echo '<select name="itemst" id="itemst">'; //select
//for the options
foreach($options as $option){
    if($dbRecord["numeric_field"] == $option){
         echo '<option value="$option" selected>$option</option>';
         //this is the selected option for the db record 
   } else {
         echo '<option value="$option">$option</option>';
   }
}
echo '</select>';

//add any other input you need
echo '<input...>';
echo '</form>';
```

Hope my answer helps you.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, this is an edit form & I need the value of a specific column from the db to display. This is the only drop-down. Within the form tags, I am getting the id: <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="<? echo $r_item['id']?>">

Comment: $options = $r_item['item_status'];

                echo '<select name="itemst" id="itemst">';
                //for the options
                foreach($options as $option){
                    if($r_item["item_status"] == $option){
                        echo '<option value="$option" selected>$option</option>';
                        //this is the selected option for the db record
                    } else {
                        echo '<option value="$option">$option</option>';
                    }
                }
                echo '</select>';

Comment: I'm doing something wrong but not sure what!  :)  My drop-down is empty.  Sorry, I am new to PHP.

Comment: Look, everytime i am creating a form on a page, when i see this problems it's usually a "bad" key name, or the database query is failing, do this on ur formpage `var_dump($r_item)` and check the keys, maybe the key name is whats failing.

Comment: var_dump($r_item) returns the correct value for this field, but using the code above, I get a blank dropdown.  Does the code look correct in the comments just above?  Thanks!

Comment: check [this](https://tio.run/##lVJNa9wwED1bv2IwAbdg1iRpTl1vD@keFgo9bKCHEhaxHq9MbclIs11C6G/fjD7sbHJKhcHS0@jNmzczqvF8Xn4b1ShEdmV3HeEANfzO/WbnSNLR5VCv4KaEXMsBwyF/UAgbjsgZdWZAUp0@7LB36X47YeAxuM4fv4qsqhhywB/xc2mtfOKdJLA4WnSoycGTOVo@741tBMQ1/eHKjNQZ7by@6/KmvC2/lHeRmPU4T4mBeoprjQ3nyFdCa80AJ4UcxnnggAQ4FAte2kDXoCwD7pQ59g380eYksjk77pWBYumwxz2Bt6IOJjnK@e28XxVB0M8Rdcid4kkeZiZ/vyVpCXpjRm/ShWiRsWqUewWf5nqlm2r/DM@BJstE5v9V9UulRKFzsWFQ12A0U7Zv7KApNAJwsoawgc0Wtusf6/uH9fdZol9dyxLiRLwdh0fP/07Q5UpOpSx/ZX9kq4pFerEo8mQKNqsLdFnFnTfwku1fHKFnMVW8ablWP0XaULSYexGLS@BEv/h/aR9SJMSrOOG7ed@bzuH7fmcpWxUxpjmfXwA) commented